# In Node.JS, how do I return an entire object from a separate .js file?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am new to Node.js and trying to figure out how to request an object from a separate file (rather than just requesting a function) but everything I try--`exports`,`module-exports`,etc--is failing.

So, for example, if I have `foo.js`:

```
    var methods = {
                   Foobar:{
                            getFoo: function(){return "foo!!";},
                            getBar: function(){return "bar!!";}
                   }
                  };
module.exports = methods;
```

And now I want to call a function within an object of `foo.js` from `index.js`:

```
var m = require('./foo');  
function fooMain(){
  return m.Foobar.getFoo();
};
```

How do I do this?  I have tried all sorts of combinations of `exports` and `module-exports` but they seem to only work if I call a discrete function that is not part of an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You said that you tried `exports`, but your code doesn't show it. Anything that you want to be visible from outside your module must be assigned to (or otherwise be referable from) `module.exports`. In your case, where you have an object already, you can just assign it to `module.exports`:

```
var methods = {
    ...
};

// You must export the methods explicitly
module.exports = methods;
```

`module.exports` isn't magic, it's a normal object, and you can treat it as such. Meaning that you could have assigned your methods directly to it, as in:

```
module.exports.Foobar = {};
module.exports.Foobar.getFoo = function() { ... };
...
```

Or, as you probably know, you could event replace it with a function:

```
module.exports = function() { return "It's ALWAYS over 9000!!!!"; };
```

Only after exporting will you be able to use *anything* in another module.

Comment: Thanks voithos!  So to be sure I understand, I need to explicitly export each part of the object (ex: `module.exports.Foobar.getFoo`)?  I was attempting to just export the entire object and then access it's constituents from `index.js` by using dot notation.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt: No, you don't need to do it individually. As I said, `module.exports` is just a normal object. So, yes, you can just assign your `methods` object to it, and everything should work out fine. I'll revise my answer to make that more explicit.